# Limit disk quota per layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tilecache

The [GeoServer user documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/diskquotas.html) for version 2.25.x states:

> The Disk Quotas page manages the disk usage for cached tiles and
> allows you to set the global disk quota. **Individual layer quotas can
> be set in the layer's properties page**.

Did this last one finally get implemented or am I missing something? Because I am not able to find in the layer's properties interface where it is possible to do it. I have searched the Internet but I can't find any reference to this feature.

Comment: Try to find out where the GeoWebCache configuration files are in the integrated installation with GeoServer. By the documentation of the standalone GWC there is a place to configure quota for each layer https://geowebcache.osgeo.org/docs/main/configuration/diskquotas.html. I could not find a place for making that configuration from the UI of GeoServer.

Comment: @user30184 Okay, thanks, I'll take a look. From what I see, when the integration between GeoServer and GeoWebCache was done, the disk quota for each layer was not added, so it is not available in the GUI. The GeoServer user documentation should [trace this error back to version 2.2.x](https://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/geoserver-users/thread/CAG9OqYpwQgb0KQzMF2%3DcxsFWcAcNwh5236XtT60yHMLN9DpboQ%40mail.gmail.com/#msg29909422).